# Pentaho CDE how use my database

Tags: pentaho, dashboard, cda

I'm trying to create a **Penaho Dashboard using CDE** and I have problems accessing my Data. 
I have found tutorials but they always use SampleData or Steel Wheels. I have managed to do that myself, but I need to access my own database.

I was able to connect with my oracle database from the Data Source manager and created my own Data Source. But now I don't know how to access those tables from CDE. If I chose "sql datasource" I see the SampleData datasource and can do queries on it, but not the one I created with my database.

So, once I create a connection with my orcale database, **how do I access my tables from CDE**?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

SQL over JDBC: you define the db host, port, name, username and password;
SQL over JNDI: it'll use a registered JNDI from the Pentaho platform.

The JNDI field is an auto-complete field and fills in the various available options. However, if your newly created connection doesn't show up there, don't worry. Just type it in, it'll work.

Comment: You were right, even thought the connection didn't appear in the Jndi list of Data Sources, I just typed the name and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you have to setup your data-source..

Click on datasources-panel on right corner
Click on sql Queries from the list you have seen on left side.
then click on sql over sqljndi
now here in properties in jndi set your database connection you want to access.

you can-not see the out-put of particular query in CDE for that open the same file in CDA for checking particular query's result(which you can find under files section).

Comment: Your way of seeing queries sounds interesting. How can I do that? You say "open the same fine in CDA". I installed CDA from the marketplace, but I thopught it was just the Data Source Manager. Where is it you mean I can test queries?

Comment: in the file section, as soon as you create any of the CDE file 1 more CDA file you will see with the same name (it will automatically going to created)..
So just open that CDA file, so their what ever you name created for connection under data-access that name will appear and you can see the query result after selecting that name..

if you reach to this point the rest of the things you will understand by your own.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was looking for a tool, but I just had to open the file.